# How do I redirect the kernel console output on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, ubuntu-10.04, ipmi

When I reboot my Ubuntu 10.04 nodes, I'd like to be able to see the kernel boot messages when connecting to the IPMI interfaces using Serial Over LAN mode (ttyS0). What do I need to do to be able to redirect these messages to ttyS0?

Ideally, I'd like them to also still appear in the usual place (tty0, I think) for when I plug a monitor directly into the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, apparently you need to edit the /etc/default/grub file and add the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS0"
```

Then run the `update-grub` command which will update /boot/grub/grub.cfg accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time since I did this but this might work.

Edit /etc/grub.conf and add the following to your kernel line

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS0
```

If that does not work you might need to make a special boot option for just serial and put the ttyS0 first and use the example as your monitor boot option

Comment: I think the grub stuff is in a different place in ubuntu, there's no /etc/grub.conf file.

Comment: chances are its in /etc/grub/grub.conf then

Comment: /boot/grub on Ubuntu